# VBA conditional formatting option for highlighting unmatching criterias

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula, conditional-formatting

I have created a spreadsheet with two tabs.

The first worksheet is named "Overview 2023" and contains the results of a rather complex formula in the range of cells D4 to AJ159. The formula can either return 0 or a numerical value

[image]

The second worksheet is named "BL GL," which displays a list of BLs in column A and their corresponding GLs in column C. The challenge here is that some BLs may have multiple associated GLs.

[image]

My goal is to apply conditional formatting via VBA or not to highlight the values within "Overview 2023" (Cells D4:AJ159) as follows:

In gray: if the cell equals zero.

In green: if the cells with values other than zero match a BL number and GL number combination found in the "BL GL" worksheet (located in columns A and C). I have tried the below but it doesn't work. =AND(D4<>0, COUNTIF('BL GL'!$D$1:$D$159, D4)>0)

In yellow: if none of the above conditions are met (meaning if the cells contain a value, but no corresponding BL GL combination is found).

To put it simply, if there is a value under D4, the cell needs to be highlighted in green if C4 and D3 have a match under the BL GL tab (match between column A and C) If the math doesn't exist, the cell should be highlighted in yellow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to have the ones that have a value in the BL column but doesn't have a matching GL value yellow: here are the formulas and img:

[image]

Yellow

> =AND(D4<>0;COUNTIFS('BL GL'!$A$2:$A$10;RIGHT($C4;LEN($C4)-2);'BL GL'!$C$2:$C$10;D$3)=0;COUNTIF('BL
> GL'!$A$2:$A$10;RIGHT($C4;LEN($C4)-2))>0)

Green

> =AND(D4<>0;COUNTIFS('BL GL'!$A$2:$A$10;RIGHT($C4;LEN($C4)-2);'BL GL'!$C$2:$C$10;D$3)>0)

Grey (think you had this one already ^^)

> =D4=0

If you want all of the ones that don't have a BL/GL match, this is the yellow one then:

> =AND(D4<>0;COUNTIFS('BL GL'!$A$2:$A$10;RIGHT($C4;LEN($C4)-2);'BL GL'!$C$2:$C$10;D$3)=0)

Just a small trim on the formula

For the formulas, you can edit the ranges for BL GL to $A:$A or the respective range you have, whichever you prefer.